# NSString memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory, nsstring, memory-leaks

```
//opening DB
if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];  //!
else
    result nil;
return result;
//close DB
```

Comment: please see my answer on this link . it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185533/memory-leak-in-nsstring-stringwithutf8string/9955130#9955130

Answer (score 2):

This is actually not a memory leak. The NSString will be autoreleased, and the `char*` returned by `sqlite3_column_text` will be cleaned up by sqlite during the next step/reset/finalize call.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the analysis fails to recognise constructors like this and think they are leaks when they aren't.

Comment: You need to post the actual output of the analyzer.   It should recognize that just fine.

Answer (score 0):

the string should be autoreleased by stringWithUTF8String, are you testing for memory leaks on the iPhone or on the simulator? Often the simulator code is just a touch buggier - try it on the device itself

Comment: yes i'm testing on a simulator, cause the device debugging is really slow:( 10x for answers, probably it's a buggy simulator